# pre-departure sequence, how to increase number of flights in the sequence

Tags: air-traffic-control, general-aviation, airport-operations

If I have number of flights ready to depart (valid TOBT) if I want to increase the number of flights in the queue by adding flights in the gaps between any 2 flights whats the minimum seperation that should be taken into consideration?

example:
suppose I have 2 flights the first one is already included in the sequence and it has CTOT. the second flight is still not included in the sequence and has no CTOT(the origin and the des airport not in Europe) and I would like to add it before the first flight since I have time between its TSAT and its TOBT.
whats the minimum seperation time that allow me to add another flight?

TOBT => Target Off Block Time (when flight is ready to push back)

CTOT => Calculated Take Off Time (given by the European control management its the slot when the flight should depart (CTOT -5/+10 min))

TSAT => Target Start up Approval Time, when ATC give permission to aircraft to start bush back from its stand

EXOT => Estimated Taxi Out Time

Comment: What are TOBT, CTOT, TSAT?

Comment: these are ACDM terms
TOBT => Target Off Block Time (when flight is ready to push back)
CTOT => Calculated Take Off Time (given by the European control management its the slot when the flight should depart (CTOT -5/+10 min))
TSAT => Target Start Approval Time, when ATC give permission to aircraft to start bush back from its stand

Comment: And what is ACDM?

Comment: ACDM => Airport Collaborative Decision Making
its a system aims to enhance the performance inside any airport
https://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/airport-collaborative-decision-making-cdm

Comment: This will depend on a number of factors, namely aircraft wake turbulence category, aircraft speed, planned departure route, aerodrome layout, whether or not surveillance (radar) is available, weather conditions, local rules for separation of departing aircraft and probably a few more I can't think of right now.

Comment: @J.Hougaard if I have a micro service to calculate the EXOT based on aircraft type, speed, weather condition and other factors, Do you think that would help me to set a fixed minimal seperation time for one runway/airport, or to calculate the seperation based on flight exot

Comment: can you provide a sample of  wake turbulence category list?

Comment: @FarahAmawi you've just introduced another acronym (EXOT) into the fray. It would be good to [edit] your post to include a definition of each of these.

Comment: @FarahAmawi you might want to improve the question by puting explanations into the question itself instead of adding comments.